# Naming conventions in UNIX C functions (_t and _st)

Tags: c, unix

I notice that there are some function return types named `*****_t` or `******_st`. What do "_st" and "_t" mean?

Comment: Which functions are you thinking of?  Types generally end `_t`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

POSIX reserves names ending `_t` for types.  Although it is quite common to see code that invents its own type names ending `_t`, doing so is dangerous - you can run into POSIX systems that define a (different) type with the same name.

---

In the libmemcached source, it looks like the `_st` suffix is used to indicate a structure type:

```
types.h:typedef struct memcached_st memcached_st;
types.h:typedef struct memcached_stat_st memcached_stat_st;
types.h:typedef struct memcached_analysis_st memcached_analysis_st;
types.h:typedef struct memcached_result_st memcached_result_st;
types.h:// All of the flavors of memcache_server_st
types.h:typedef struct memcached_server_st memcached_server_st;
types.h:typedef const struct memcached_server_st *memcached_server_instance_st;
types.h:typedef struct memcached_server_st *memcached_server_list_st;
```

I didn't find a single instance of a function ending `_st` (but I may not have looked hard enough).

Comment: nice. In libmemcached source, there many function return types are end with "_t" or "_st". for example

Comment: static memcached_server_st *_server_create(memcached_server_st *self, const memcached_st *memc). and so does many other libs.

Comment: thank you Jonathan Leffler, I think i am clear with this anyway